# Disable editing of multiple objects in Blender 2.8

Tags: 3d-view, interface, edit-mode, workflow, object-mode

In Blender 2.8, if you have multiple objects selected in Object Mode, and then hit Tab to enter Edit Mode, ALL the selected objects (both the yellow active object and the orange selected-but-inactive objects) will be editable. This is new behaviour for 2.8, and while it certainly has its uses, it can also cause unexpected problems if you only want to edit the single active object.

So I'm wondering: is there any way to disable this feature? I can't seem to find one, but it seems too obvious an option to be unavailable??

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you need to select both of the objects if you just want to edit the single active object ?

Comment: I think if you utilize the new grouping method, then you will change your behavior in editing the object. And is there any shortcoming that both object entering edit mode?

Comment: You could make  the objects you don't want to edit non selectable. Probably need more information on your workflow and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: To clarify: I'm asking this because it's easy (for me, anyway) to accidentally select multiple objects, and to thus find myself editing vertices I don't want to edit. This problem is exacerbated by Blender remembering which vertices were active last time each object was in edit mode, which can mean if I've inadvertently selected multiple objects, I can discover hours later that vertices that were off-screen have been moved or deleted at some point when I didn't realize that object was being edited. It's not the end of the world, but it'd be nice to be able to turn the feature off.

Comment: @BintangSenja A good example of a time you need to select both of the objects and enter edit mode is when you want to vertex parent an object.  The presence of the child object's verts, usually exactly on top of the verts you want to select for the parenting, complicates this procedure.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments I can see your problem is due to having other objects selected and not knowing about them. Not a real solution for your problem but, whenever I'm modelling with several objects, as a good practice I always tap <kbd>A</kbd> twice to deselect everything before selecting the object (I use the Blender 2.79 hotkeys). There are many advantages in being able to go to edit mode with multiple objects and I'm sure you will soon make use of them as well.

Update: For Blender 2.8 it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to deselect anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the ability to select objects through filters. Once *selectable* is disabled you can't accidentally select the object anymore. In the example below Cube.001 and Cube.002 can't be selected in the 3D View until *selectable* is activated again.

This is not the same as deactivating the multi-object editing, however I don't think there is an option for that.

[image]

[image]